# Maximum boxes that can fit in a given pallet [Box & Pallet Dimensions are user defined]

Tags: java, algorithm

[image: Box Arrangement]

Problem Statement:
For a user defined box & pallet dimensions, maximum boxes to be arranged to maximize utilisation of space. **Programming Language Used: Java**

The above link shows an example image. I am stuck on how to effectively & consistently solve this problem for any given user input. Can anybody please suggest which algorithm & approach would be good to begin with.

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Reinaldo_Morabito/publication/233653794_An_effective_recursive_partitioning_approach_for_the_packing_of_identical_rectangles_in_a_rectangle/links/0c960538766ff1f4b1000000.pdf

Comment: Do you require the boxes to be aligned with the axes?